# SVG Infographic WHILE, WHILE, WHILE

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to create an infographic which creates 36 circles in a formation where the color of the circles is derived from 36 divided by a percentage value in a data set.

*** EDIT - I have changed to a working script which has no loops ****

I have made the variables work correctly, it now knows that on_value is 15 (36 * input_data.metric_value percentage of 0.42), off_value is 21 and square is 36. I made 100% be 36 because I can divide by 2 and 3 easily.

I also know that my ROUND function is working correctly.

The script below now produces a single circle. However, the logic I want to implement is for it to create 36 circles using either first color for the first 15 circles then change to the second color for the next 21 circles as it works its way through a loop.

I believe there it should loop 6 times through columns per row and loop through 6 rows which is a total of 36.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg id="mysvg" height="310" width="250">
   <text x="125" y="260" fill="#FF9900"
        font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
        text-anchor="middle"
        font-size="42">42%</text>

  <text x="125" y="290" fill="#FF9900"
        font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
        text-anchor="middle"
        font-size="28">PROFITABLE</text>

  <script type="application/ecmascript">
  <![CDATA[
      var mysvg = document.getElementById("mysvg");

      var input_data = {performance_metrics: [
        {metric_name: "Profitability",
         metric_value: 0.42}
        ]};

      var on_value = 0;
      var off_value = 0;

   input_data.performance_metrics.forEach(e=>{
     on_value = Math.round(36 * e.metric_value)
     off_value = 36 - on_value});

   var square = 36; 
   var row = 1;
   var col = 1;
   var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
         circle.setAttribute("cx", 20 + (1 * 30));
         circle.setAttribute("cy", 20 + (1 * 30));
         circle.setAttribute("r", "10");
          if (square < on_value) {
            circle.setAttribute("style", "fill","#FF9900");
            circle.setAttribute("stroke","black");
            circle.setAttribute("stroke-width","0")
            circle.setAttribute("opacity","1");
              }
          else {
            circle.setAttribute("style", "fill","#E8E8E8");
            circle.setAttribute("stroke","black");
            circle.setAttribute("stroke-width","0")
            circle.setAttribute("opacity","1")};



  mysvg.appendChild(circle);

  function formatNumber(num) {
    return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,')
    }

   ]]>
</script>
</svg>

</body>
```

The finished output should look like the image in this post

[image: profitability infographic]

I started with doing the svg manually and then committed to creating it using while looks. Here's the code of it working explicitly

```
<svg height="310" width="250">
  <text x="125" y="260" fill="#FF9900"
   font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
   text-anchor="middle"
   font-size="42">42%</text>

 <text x="125" y="290" fill="#FF9900"
   font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
   text-anchor="middle"
   font-size="28">PROFITABLE</text>

 <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#FF9900" />
 <circle cx="80" cy="50" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#FF9900" />
 <circle cx="110" cy="50" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#FF9900" />
 <circle cx="140" cy="50" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#FF9900" />
 <circle cx="170" cy="50" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#FF9900" />
 <circle cx="200" cy="50" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#FF9900" />

 <circle cx="50" cy="80" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#FF9900" />
 <circle cx="80" cy="80" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#FF9900" />
 <circle cx="110" cy="80" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#FF9900" />
 <circle cx="140" cy="80" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#FF9900" />
 <circle cx="170" cy="80" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#FF9900" />
 <circle cx="200" cy="80" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#FF9900" />

 <circle cx="50" cy="110" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#FF9900" />
 <circle cx="80" cy="110" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#FF9900" />
 <circle cx="110" cy="110" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#FF9900" />
 <circle cx="140" cy="110" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#E8E8E8" />
 <circle cx="170" cy="110" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#E8E8E8" />
 <circle cx="200" cy="110" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#E8E8E8" />

 <circle cx="50" cy="140" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#E8E8E8" />
 <circle cx="80" cy="140" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#E8E8E8" />
 <circle cx="110" cy="140" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#E8E8E8" />
 <circle cx="140" cy="140" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#E8E8E8" />
 <circle cx="170" cy="140" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#E8E8E8" />
 <circle cx="200" cy="140" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#E8E8E8" />

 <circle cx="50" cy="170" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#E8E8E8" />
 <circle cx="80" cy="170" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#E8E8E8" />
 <circle cx="110" cy="170" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#E8E8E8" />
 <circle cx="140" cy="170" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#E8E8E8" />
 <circle cx="170" cy="170" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#E8E8E8" />
 <circle cx="200" cy="170" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#E8E8E8" />

 <circle cx="50" cy="200" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#E8E8E8" />
 <circle cx="80" cy="200" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#E8E8E8" />
 <circle cx="110" cy="200" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#E8E8E8" />
 <circle cx="140" cy="200" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#E8E8E8" />
 <circle cx="170" cy="200" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#E8E8E8" />
 <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" fill="#E8E8E8" />
 Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
</svg>
```

The calculations for on_value is round(36 × performance_metrics.metric_value)

42% = 15 dots.

I made it 6 x 6 because you can divide by 2 and 3.

There is a row loop 1 to 6 inside of a column loop 1 - 6

Sets colour to color 1 (orange) until count 1 to 36 surpasses 15 then color 2 (grey)

Circle x is 20 + (row loop value x 30)
Circle y is 20 + (column loop Vale x 30)

Circle radius is 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are struggling with creating the grid of circles, you could achieve it with 2 for loops.

```js
var mysvg = document.getElementById("mysvg");
//mysvg.setAttribute('height', 500)

var data = 0.42

var gridWidth = 6;
var gridHeight = 6;
var circleRadius = 10;
var count = 0

for (let i = 0; i < gridWidth; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < gridHeight; j++) {
    count++
    var isFilled = count / (gridWidth * gridHeight) > data
    var circle = document.createElementNS(
      "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
      "circle"
    );
    circle.setAttribute("cx", 20 + j * 30);
    circle.setAttribute("cy", 20 + i * 30);
    circle.setAttribute("r", circleRadius);
    circle.setAttribute("fill", isFilled ? 'blue' : 'red');
    mysvg.appendChild(circle);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- <svg id="mysvg"></svg> -->
<svg id="mysvg" viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="width:100%;"></svg>
```

Comment: crickey, that is a beautiful thing to behold :) Thank you

Comment: I think maybe svg size is short as the 6th row is missing @ksav

Comment: Whoops. The last row was getting cut off because the SVG element didn't have a height set.

Comment: Conversely, we could set a viewbox on the `SVG` element, and have it scale to 100% of available width.

Comment: like that a lot, I've inserted it into a script which allows me to download it as a png so that I can create infographics on the fly from data as and when received. I tried the viewbox option before when I created the download script and it played havoc with the resolution of the image file

Answer (score 1):

there are a few small mistakes and one big one.
small mistakes first on line 41 & 42 you missed a ")" at the end.
on lines 45 & 48 you switched to css syntax halfway through the parenthesis.
but your biggest problem is on line 44, on_value is identified inside a function on line 26
and thus can't be seen outside of it.

Comment: thanks for your help, I fixed up the missing ")"s, completely missed that, thanks. I am trying to work out how to get `on_value` to be available for use within those loops to set the colour in the IF statement. Still stumped.

Comment: from console, I cannot find any of my variables, I moved the rounding function up the script before the while but still no good

Comment: on_value should = 15, off_value should equal 21, num is 36, row is 6 and col is 6 but in console nothing gets "is not defined"